# TouchAction class is showing error on press method

Tags: java, android, appium, appium-android

this is my first project in appium and very new to this,

my Appium Java client version is 7.1.0,

I am trying to scroll up on a pop up, the issue is if I click outside the pop up which covering only like a small portion of the screen pop up will be closing and I cannot scroll up, so I am trying to touch on the pop up and then scroll, but when I try the below code, it seems like showing a red line and error on .touch function of TouchAction class, please help me with this,

I am using MobileDriver as driver,

attaching the screenshot for reference,

thanks

```
TouchAction actions = new TouchAction(driver);
actions.press(startX, startY).waitAction(Duration.ofSeconds(2)).moveTo(endX, endY).release().perform();
```

Comment: The screenshot is missing.

Comment: I was not able to add screenshot, how to attach? I am able to scroll now but the scroll is happening in a model which is popping up on the log in page, so the model is giving me the radio button which is not in the visible area of the screen. and trying to click that by clicking outside the model, and model is getting closed, how can I get the elements which is only visible in the screen...